# How exactly does GridView recycle/reuse view in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-recyclerview, android-memory

I think I do understand the mechanism of reusing views for ListView, but for GridView, the way it recycles the views are not in expectation.

in my sample ,i just simply recycle the view if convertView is not null in `getView()` from Adapter.

Also I log the position of the view.

[image]

but the strange thing is after I check the logcat, I found even if i did not scroll at all, the view from position 0(the first vi!ew) is not null(**at the very first time no recycled view so convertView for positon 0 should be null right?**).

[image]

even stranger thing is , after it logs all 54 items (as you can see the whole screen can hold 54 views), it logs serveral position 0 's recycled view

[image]

so it totally confuses me the way GridView recycle views. In my opinion it should be something like ListView, if I scroll down, the top views go off from the screen, then they go back to the bottom of the list one by one, but seems like in GridView its not.

**I even use HashMap to calculate the recycle times of each View(by String to Integer Entry, Key is the `toString()` value of a view), i found the recycle times are not distributed equally, while some of the view has 30 times of recycle while some of them have just once.....**

---

**Edit(add the recycle codes and also the screenshot for exception)**

[image]

[image]

```
(Edit) even though I tried using `setImageDrawable(null)` it still throws exception, as noticed you can see the exception will be thrown no matter I called it before or after the recycle
```

[image]
[image]

I think the point to this issue is Android is not handling recycled view as I expected, so my guess is even if a convertView is not null, it does not prove it is going off the screen, as you answered before, android will use the position 0 item to do initial measurement, so it may be the root cause.

```
**Edit Again**
```

**Adapter code:**

```
 package com.example.photoswalldemo;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.util.LruCache;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AbsListView;
    import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.GridView;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    /**
     * GridView的适配器，负责异步从网络上下载图片展示在照片墙上。
     * 
     * @author guolin
     */
    public class PhotoWallAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnScrollListener {

        /**
         * 记录所有正在下载或等待下载的任务。
         */
        private Set<BitmapWorkerTask> taskCollection;

        /**
         * 图片缓存技术的核心类，用于缓存所有下载好的图片，在程序内存达到设定值时会将最少最近使用的图片移除掉。
         */
        private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

        /**
         * GridView的实例
         */
        private GridView mPhotoWall;

        /**
         * 第一张可见图片的下标
         */
        private int mFirstVisibleItem;

        /**
         * 一屏有多少张图片可见
         */
        private int mVisibleItemCount;

        /**
         * 记录是否刚打开程序，用于解决进入程序不滚动屏幕，不会下载图片的问题。
         */
        private boolean isFirstEnter = true;


        private RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());



        public PhotoWallAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects,
                GridView photoWall) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            mPhotoWall = photoWall;
            taskCollection = new HashSet<BitmapWorkerTask>();
            // 获取应用程序最大可用内存
            int maxMemory = (int) Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
            int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
            // 设置图片缓存大小为程序最大可用内存的1/8
            mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
                @Override
                protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    return bitmap.getByteCount();
                }
            };
            mPhotoWall.setOnScrollListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           // Log.e("Monitor View","This View is on position "+position+" and its "+convertView);
            final String url = getItem(position);
            View view;
            if (convertView == null) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.photo_layout, null);
            } else {

                View tmp=convertView;

    //            ImageView tmp1=(ImageView)tmp.findViewById(R.id.photo);
    //            if(tmp1.getDrawable()!=null){
    //                //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"it has Drawable!,",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //                Log.e("Monitor View", "This View is on position " + position + " and its view " + convertView+" and this drawable is "+tmp1.getDrawable());
    //
    //                Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)tmp1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    //                tmp1.setImageDrawable(null);
    //                tmp1.setImageBitmap(null);
    //                bitmap.recycle();
    //                bitmap=null;
    //                //tmp1.setImageDrawable(null);


            //    }


                view = convertView;


            }
            final ImageView photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo);
            // 给ImageView设置一个Tag，保证异步加载图片时不会乱序
            photo.setTag(url);
            setImageView(url, photo);
            return view;
        }

        /**
         * 给ImageView设置图片。首先从LruCache中取出图片的缓存，设置到ImageView上。如果LruCache中没有该图片的缓存，
         * 就给ImageView设置一张默认图片。
         * 
         * @param imageUrl
         *            图片的URL地址，用于作为LruCache的键。
         * @param imageView
         *            用于显示图片的控件。
         */
        private void setImageView(String imageUrl, ImageView imageView) {
            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemoryCache(imageUrl);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_photo);
            }
        }

        /**
         * 将一张图片存储到LruCache中。
         * 
         * @param key
         *            LruCache的键，这里传入图片的URL地址。
         * @param bitmap
         *            LruCache的键，这里传入从网络上下载的Bitmap对象。
         */
        public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (getBitmapFromMemoryCache(key) == null) {
                mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
            }
        }

        /**
         * 从LruCache中获取一张图片，如果不存在就返回null。
         * 
         * @param key
         *            LruCache的键，这里传入图片的URL地址。
         * @return 对应传入键的Bitmap对象，或者null。
         */
        public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemoryCache(String key) {
            return mMemoryCache.get(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // 仅当GridView静止时才去下载图片，GridView滑动时取消所有正在下载的任务
            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                loadBitmaps(mFirstVisibleItem, mVisibleItemCount);
            } else {
                cancelAllTasks();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                int totalItemCount) {
            mFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
            mVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
            // 下载的任务应该由onScrollStateChanged里调用，但首次进入程序时onScrollStateChanged并不会调用，
            // 因此在这里为首次进入程序开启下载任务。
            if (isFirstEnter && visibleItemCount > 0) {
                loadBitmaps(firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount);
                isFirstEnter = false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * 加载Bitmap对象。此方法会在LruCache中检查所有屏幕中可见的ImageView的Bitmap对象，
         * 如果发现任何一个ImageView的Bitmap对象不在缓存中，就会开启异步线程去下载图片。
         * 
         * @param firstVisibleItem
         *            第一个可见的ImageView的下标
         * @param visibleItemCount
         *            屏幕中总共可见的元素数
         */
        private void loadBitmaps(int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount) {
            try {
                for (int i = firstVisibleItem; i < firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount; i++) {
                    String imageUrl = Images.imageThumbUrls[i];
                    Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemoryCache(imageUrl);
                    if (bitmap == null) {
                        //BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask();
                        //taskCollection.add(task);
                        //task.execute(imageUrl);

                        //new method , use volley

                        useVolley(imageUrl);
                    } else {
                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mPhotoWall.findViewWithTag(imageUrl);
                        if (imageView != null && bitmap != null) {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * 取消所有正在下载或等待下载的任务。
         */
        public void cancelAllTasks() {
            if (taskCollection != null) {
                for (BitmapWorkerTask task : taskCollection) {
                    task.cancel(false);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * 异步下载图片的任务。
         * 
         * @author guolin
         */
        class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

            /**
             * 图片的URL地址
             */
            private String imageUrl;

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                imageUrl = params[0];
                // 在后台开始下载图片
                Bitmap bitmap = downloadBitmap(params[0]);
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    // 图片下载完成后缓存到LrcCache中
                    addBitmapToMemoryCache(params[0], bitmap);
                }
                return bitmap;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
                // 根据Tag找到相应的ImageView控件，将下载好的图片显示出来。
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mPhotoWall.findViewWithTag(imageUrl);
                if (imageView != null && bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                taskCollection.remove(this);
            }

            /**
             * 建立HTTP请求，并获取Bitmap对象。
             * 
             * @param imageUrl
             *            图片的URL地址
             * @return 解析后的Bitmap对象
             */
            private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String imageUrl) {
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                HttpURLConnection con = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
                    con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    con.setConnectTimeout(5 * 1000);
                    con.setReadTimeout(10 * 1000);
                    con.setDoInput(true);
                    con.setDoOutput(true);
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(con.getInputStream());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (con != null) {
                        con.disconnect();
                    }
                }
                return bitmap;
            }

        }



        private void useVolley(String url){

            final String tmpurl=url;

           // ImageView tmpImageView=(ImageView)mPhotoWall.findViewWithTag(tmpurl);
            ImageRequest imageRequest=new ImageRequest(url,new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {

                    ImageView tmpImageView=(ImageView)mPhotoWall.findViewWithTag(tmpurl);

                    tmpImageView.setImageBitmap(response);

                    mMemoryCache.put(tmpurl,response);
                }
            },0, 0, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    ImageView tmpImageView=(ImageView)mPhotoWall.findViewWithTag(tmpurl);
                    //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image);
                    tmpImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.empty_photo);
                }
            });



            this.queue.add(imageRequest);

        }

    }
```

**Main Activity Code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * 用于展示照片墙的GridView
     */
    private GridView mPhotoWall;

    /**
     * GridView的适配器
     */
    private PhotoWallAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mPhotoWall = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.photo_wall);
        adapter = new PhotoWallAdapter(this, 0, Images.imageThumbUrls, mPhotoWall);
        mPhotoWall.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // 退出程序时结束所有的下载任务
        adapter.cancelAllTasks();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code for your adapter and how you set this adapter to the view?

Comment: hi Karmazi Ive updated the post for my 1.MainActivity and 2.Adapter, basically I have a gridview in layout, and I set adapter in my mainactivity, Thanks man

Comment: Got a modified version of this to work but load on scroll is slow. Probably a factor of cache size/image size being processed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are inflating the view if it's null and reusing it if it's not null is exactly correct.  This is the way the `AdapterView` subclass achieves recycling of its views.

I was initially puzzled as you were about list item 0 having a non-null view; but then I remembered that the `AdapterView` calls the adapter to get list view 0 *several times* during the measuring and laying out phase before even displaying the list item.  It sounds unnecessary, but obviously the Google developer must have had a reason for doing so.  This also explains why you see the multiple logs for list item 0.

As for the uneven recycling, I can't remember if the views are recycled FIFO or LIFO, but the point is that it doesn't matter.  If you specified (through `getItemViewType()` that the layouts are the same, then it doesn't matter which one the `AdapterView` hands you to recycle.  If all you want is an aluminum can, do you really care if it's Coke or Pepsi?

Also consider that the views at the very top of the `AdapterView` are typically going off and on the screen much more frequently than the views further down, and I think this is what accounts for the lopsided distribution of view recycling that you are observing.

---

EDIT: On your exception:  You are calling `bitmap.recycle()` then setting `bitmap = null`.  But keep in mind, even though you set `bitmap = null` the `Drawable` still holds a reference to the bitmap which is now marked as recycled!  So when the `ImageView` tries to draw it notices that the bitmap has been marked as recycled so an exception get thrown.  If you call `tmp1.setImageDrawable(null)` after dealing with the bitmap, the exception should go away.

Comment: the point I asked this question is, as you can see the convertView contains a ImageView, the imageview points to a bitmap and I want to recycle() it.

Comment: what I did is if the convertView is not null, then it was used before and this view is going off the screen so I no longer need it, hence I can free the memory for this view's bitmap, but when I did it it throws out exception like garbage bitmap which is still in used or something, which doesnt make sense since the convertView is going off the screen and will be recycled...

Comment: so thats why I need to figure out how does GridView handled the recycled views, like its manipulation sequence or stuff, if not it can not explained why I get fatal exceptions even if i recycled bitmap from convertView which is going off the screen.

Comment: Can you post the exception message with the first few lines of stack trace so I can see the exception and where in Android code it's being thrown from?

Comment: Hi Kris Ive updated the post,  thanks for the investigation ;)

Comment: Hey Kris, I tried , but its not working, I think you were right about eliminating the reference to the bitmap first then recycle. But I think the point is, even if converView is not null, it cant be proved that it goes off the screen, just like what you said for the position 0 item.

Comment: It's an interesting problem, because that bitmap memory needs to be managed well to avoid OutOfMemoryErrors, yet the user can always scroll backward and the view ends up needing the bitmap again.  I have the same problem with my app, sometimes my image-intensive lists cause OOMs.  If I find any interesting information on this topic in the near future, I'll update my answer.  Cheers

Comment: Hi Kris, thanks, im also very confused that I can hardly find any correct explaination in statckoverflow, no one really care about bitmap recycle?haah, i think i need dive into the source code to find that out. but I will mark your response as answer anyway, thanks ;)